# Массивы и объекты в JS

Tags: javascript

До этого времени не уделял особо внимание этому,а сегодня столкнулся и потратил немного времени.В чем разница между массивом и объектов в JS? Нужно было сделать многомерный массив и потом все это преобразовать в JSON.Так вот погуглил и наткнулся на статьи о том что в JS нет многомерных массивов,аналогом являются объекты.Так вот хочется понять разницу между ними.

Comment: Не, ну серьезно, почитать офф документацию не пробовали?

Comment: На счет объекта не знаю, но хочу сказать по поводу многомерного массива. Да ладно ты не парься, есть в JS многомерные массивы. Если будет var al = new Array(1, "something", false, 0.75),  и потом var arr = newArray(al, "asdk", false) – то это уже многомерный массив.

Comment: а можно ссылку на _статьи о том что в JS нет многомерных массивов, **аналогом являются объекты**_?

Answer (score 1):

В JavaScipt массив является объектом со специфическими свойствами и методами. Многомерные массивы так же возможны.
Подробнее: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Здравствуйте **@Khipster**! считаю, что если вы начали ответ писать, сделайте его полным, `специфическими свойствами и методами`, что это за специфические методы и свойства? Считаю, что в данном виде ваш ответ был бы неплохим в виде комментария к вопросу, но в виде ответа - получите минус от меня. Если улучшите ответ, с радостью сниму минус.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov Нужно было описать пару свойств и методов? Или вдаться в теорию ООП? Или засыпать терминами вроде standard built-in object?

Comment: Вы решили написать ответ, вы и решайте что там будет, я могу лишь повторить то, что в данном виде ваш ответ был бы неплох в виде комментария к вопросу. Надеюсь вы посмотрите объективно и возможно со мной согласитесь. Вы можете удалить его и написать в виде комментария, и я поставлю комментарию плюс, или отредактировать его и сделать более полным и я уберу минус и возможно поставлю плюс.